# what is the difference between rsnapshot and rdiffbackup?

Tags: backup, rsync

What is the difference between [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) and [rdiffbackup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/)?

Which is better for backing up a new snapshot of my laptop (over the Internet from some remote location) to my server (which already has the previous backup) ?

As far as I can tell, they both store (on the backup server) the latest backup and many previous versions of backed-up files (in the form of compressed reverse-incremental deltas).
They both use rsync to make backups over the internet faster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting from http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/02/backup-on-linux-rsnapshot-vs-rdiff/ :

> For rsnapshot, all versions of the backup are accessible as plain
>   files. For rdiff-backup, only the current backup is accessible as
>   plain files. Previous versions are stored as rdiff deltas.

also:

> For small files, storage size is similar. For large files that change
>   often, such as logfiles, databases, etc., rdiff-backup requires
>   significantly less space for a given number of versions.

The page lists some other differences also.

Answer (score 4):

I Would add, for the sake of completeness that there exists [rbackup](http://rbackup.lescigales.org) which is just a wrapper script around `rdiff-backup`to ease snapshot management, more like `rsnapshot`'s way of managing snapshots (easier to configure).